# Serviço de Aplicativo compartilhada do Azure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, microsoft-azure, hospedagem

Bom dia pessoal !
Estou desenvolvendo um portal de entretenimento no qual terá imagens e texto (ex.: Terra ou UOL), utilizando ASP.NET e sql-server. Estava analisando sobre o Azure e me surgiu uma dúvida: 
O serviço de aplicativo compartilhado é semelhante aos serviço de hospedagens oferecidas por outros ( ex: Kinghost, Uolhost ) ? É que na documentação do Azure, o mesmo recomenda somente para testes. Mas posso usá-lo para produção ? Há algum limite ou desvantagem perante aos serviços superiores ?
Agradeço antecipadamente pela ajuda !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Azure, um plano de cobrança do tipo compartilhado, você não consegue garantir um mínimo de recursos (processamento e memória) dedicado à sua aplicação. Esse é o motivo pelo qual não se recomenda utilizar esse plano como o de produção, pois hora você terá o máximo de recurso disponível - que deve ser 0.25 core e 750mb memória - e hora nem isso terá, experimentando grande lentidão.

O ideal, para ambiente de produção, é dedicar recursos para sua aplicação, assinando planos da série Basic para cima. De acordo com que seu processo de publicação de aplicação for exigindo mais controle, já poderá passar a trabalhar com a série Standard e controlar publicações e experimenta com recursos como slots, etc.

Sobre mais limitações, você pode ver na página de [Preços de Serviços de Aplicativos](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/pricing/details/app-service/).

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento !

Answer (score 2):

O serviço de aplicativo compartilhado é adequado por sites pequenos com pouco transito. Por um portal de entretenimento, provavalmente você precisará um nível mais alto, como Thiago disse.

O serviço do Azul é flexível e você pode mudar o nível a qualquer momento; leva só segundos. Você pode selecionar a escala de um site em dois métodos: "scale up" e "scale out". O primeiro, scale up, estabelece o tamanho da maquina.

(Os preços na imagem são em GBP e por um centro na Europa. Desculpe-me pelo incómodo, mas não quero mudar os meus parâmetros. Para dar uma ideia, 1 GBP = 5 BRL mais ou menos.)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segundo, scale out, é o número de maquinas. Pode usar isto com niveis Basic, Standard, e Premium. Assim como processar mais carga, oferece redundância então é mais confiavel.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O número de maquinas (instances) pode ser fixo ou automaticamente variavel, dependente na carga.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro, a custa pode ser considerável com os niveis mais altos, mas o serviço do Azure é muito conveniente e tem muitas vantagens, inclusive flexibilidade, enorme poder, e locações pelo mundo.

Veja "Dimensionar um aplicativo Web no Serviço de Aplicativo do Azure" -- https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/

Se a aplicação for internacional, pode a pôr em múltiplo centros de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja "Regiões do Azure, Amplo alcance global" -- https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/regions/

Se o site tiver muitas imagens, vídeos, etc, você poderia considerar a Rede de Fornecimento de Conteúdo do Azure -- https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/cdn/

Se a sua empresa seja "start up", pode inscrever-se na programa Microsoft Bizspark que oferece recursos do Azure gratis -- http://www.micbh.com.br/Paginas/Bizspark.aspx

Comment: Novamente, agradeço pelo esclarecimento. Mas o custo é alto para mim, então, continuarei na hospedagem que tenho (por enquanto).

Comment: Admiro que você tem uma ideia e está criando um site. Use imaginação e aproveite a oportunidade que Azure traz.